# Is this method correct to find second or third or fourth highest value in a column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table (name "friend") in mysql and i want to select 2nd or 3rd or 4th highest amount (i.e salary) from that table.

I am using this method:

```
`select * from friends order by salary desc limit 1; -- for highest salary.`
```

and

```
`select * from friends order by salary desc limit 1 offset 1; -- for second highest salary.`
```

and

```
`select * from friends order by salary desc limit 1 offset 2; -- for third highest salary.`
```

is this method correct or do I have to use another logical method like.

```
`select * from friends where salary = (select max(salary) from friends where salary < (select max(salary) from friends)); -- for second highest salary`.
```

please tell me which is the professional method.

Comment: limit offset is fine. less code is good!

Answer (score 0):

The limit with offset is preferred and more legibale;

```
select * 
from friends 
order by salary desc 
limit 3,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two approaches is time complexity

In a general sense sorting (or doing an order by) only to look at highest or second highest or such is an overkill in terms of time. Think of if you want to find the largest element in a list, would you look to sort the entire list and look at the first element after sorting it, or loop through the list to find the largest one.

There is no right way, it depends on if you can afford taking slightly more time in arriving at the solution, in favour of more readable query, this would in turn be dependent on size of data etc.